# How to load gltf files in react.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I am trying to load a `glTF` file in my `reactjs` application using `gltf` loader. I manage to display a basic cube on the canvas, but using the `gltf` loader I only get the blank canvas without the 3D object.

I have tried several paths to the file but it seems to sit in the correct position (same folder as component). I have also tried other `glTF` files without luck. Do i need to include the bin file somewhere?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import GLTFLoader from 'three-gltf-loader';


const OrbitControls = require("three-orbit-controls") (THREE);

class Viewer extends Component{


  componentDidMount(){
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight

    //ADD SCENE
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene()

    //ADD CAMERA
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      width / height,
      0.1,
      1000
    )
    this.camera.position.z = 4

    //ADD RENDERER
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
    this.renderer.setClearColor('#888888')
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height)
    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)

    //ADD ORBIT CONTROL
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera,     this.renderer.domElement);

    //ADD CUBE
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#433F81'    })
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    this.scene.add(this.cube)

    //ADD OBJECT
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
      loader.load('model.gltf', (object) => {
        this.scene.add(object.scene);
      });

    this.animate();

  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.stop()
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement)
  }

  animate = () => {
   this.renderScene()
   this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
 }

  renderScene = () => {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div
        style={{ width: '400px', height: '400px' }}
        ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default Viewer;
```

The application should show the 3D file on the canvas.

**NOTE:** I'm new to three.js, so layman terms would be appreciated.

Comment: [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html) is not react specific but it does load a gLTF file. Issues you might be running into include your camera not facing the model or having it's frustum too big or too small. Another issue might be you need to add lights.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn gltf files to JSX and use react-three-fiber to reconcile threejs. Here's an example: https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/tree/3.x/tools three-fiber wraps threejs similar to how react-dom wraps html, reconcilers don't necessarily change the rules, which makes it less of an abstraction as it seems.